# Why subquery inside recursive string concatenation always returns NULL?

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2005

Suppose I have two tables:

- TABLE1: Has a list of IDs I need to process.
- TABLE2: Has key-value pairs of ID's and values.

I need to retrieve the values from TABLE2 for all the IDs in TABLE1, as a single string. In order to achieve this, I made the next query:

```
DECLARE @id INT, @value VARCHAR(10);

SELECT @id=0, @value='';

SELECT
    @value = @value + (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM TABLE2 WHERE id=@id) + '-',
    @id = @id+1
FROM TABLE1
```

But when I run this query, the subquery always returns null (and, therefore, `@value=NULL` at the end). My question is: Why does the subquery `SELECT TOP 1 value FROM TABLE2 WHERE id=@id` always returns NULL, even if the ID is found in TABLE2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very weird way of trying to implement a treewalker, increasing @id in the SELECT and expecting it to apply to the subquery.  It doesn't work because SQL Server locks the value of @id for the subquery expression as a constant right at the query setup phase.

See this example, where the returned @value clearly indicates that @id is locked at 1.  With your question, it was locked at 0, hence each subquery will return NULL, ostensibly because there is no match for @id = 0.

```
create table table1 (
  id int);
create table table2 (
  id int, value varchar(10));
insert table1 values (1),(2),(3),(4);
insert table2 values
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(4,4);

DECLARE @id INT, @value VARCHAR(10);

SELECT @id=1, @value='';

SELECT
    @value = @value + (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM TABLE2 WHERE id=@id) + '-',
    @id = @id+1
FROM TABLE1;

select @value, @id

-- result
1-1-1-1       5
```

If you merely wanted the values from 2, then instead of the variable @id, you just correlate the subquery to the table.id as below:

```
create table table1 (id int);
create table table2 (id int, value varchar(10));
insert table1 values (1),(2),(3),(4);
insert table2 values
(1,1),
(3,9),
(4,4);

DECLARE @value VARCHAR(10);

SELECT @value='';

SELECT
    @value = @value + isnull((SELECT TOP 1 value 
                              FROM TABLE2 
                              WHERE id=table1.id) + '-','')
FROM TABLE1;

select @value

-- Result
1-9-4
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm curious to know why the subquery returns NULL allways.

Comment: Because the first thing it does is (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM TABLE2 WHERE id=0) which evaluates to null, and null + 'value' = null

Comment: I guess I have to give up with this way, and use a while loop instead. For future references, can I use a CTE instead of this approach?

Comment: I don't think you need a while loop or CTE. There are two other answers that do what you wanted. Unless you needed to group the values or something like that, which you didn't mention.

Comment: @Giscard Biamby, this was just a short example to show my question, but what I'm actually doing is a lot more complex than this. I can't use the other examples because I need the last ID, not the current ID, for each loop.

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi that's what I would want to do, but I just can't explain the mess I currently have, hehehe. I'm tying to build an HTML table with subgroups and subtotals. I have the data in TABLE1, and the subtotals in TABLE2.

Comment: I think you should post the full details!

Comment: @guillegr123 - Best thing to do is to post a new question with a few rows of dummy data for tables 1 and 2 and desired results for that data.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you, because you have proposed valid answers to this specific question. I'll post a new and more detailed question about what I need tomorrow, because I almost get out of work.

Comment: Question posted, sorry for the delay: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729929/how-to-build-an-html-table-with-subtotals-using-a-recursive-string-concatenation

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution (this one only appends the '-' delimiter between values from table2 if the value from table2 is NOT NULL):

```
declare @id int, @value varchar(max);
select @id = 0, @value='';

select 
    @value = @value + isnull(value,'') + case when value is null then '' else '-' end
from 
    table2 t2
where 
    t2.id in (select id from table1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are starting your @id at 0. Unless you have an id of 0 in your table, you probably need to do: SELECT @id=1

Alternately, you could condense it to this and not use the id:

```
SELECT @value = @value + value +  '-'
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
```